# how to pass jquery variables using php session variables

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
 <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
                <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_driver">
                <span>
                Add another Driver
                <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div> 


<script>    
 var count = 0;
 jQuery("#add_driver").click(function(){
 count++;
 }); </script>
```

how can i pass the value of the variable count to the next page using php sessions or any other method? 
is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: you can use ajax to pass value to next page

Comment: is there no way other than ajax?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i need to pass the values to the other page that's it.

Comment: Then it sounds like sending the value to the next page in the querystring would be the simplest way

Comment: @NEETHI you can make use of forms since your using javascript better make use of ajax

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you tell the code?

Comment: @sam i do not know ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Below code you can send count value to secondpage.php and in second page use `$_POST['count_var']` to access variable. You can check your success response in `success: function (response)`

```
<script>    
 var count = 0;
 jQuery("#add_driver").click(function(){
 count++;
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'secondpage.php',
                        data: {
                            count_var: count,

                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                             document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML = response;
                        }
                    });
 }); 

 </script>
```

Comment: it is the id where u want to show your response, Ex : id of <div> tag

Answer (score 1):

use localStorage

**page one**

```
var count = 0;
 jQuery("#add_driver").click(function(){
     count++;
     localStorage.setItem("count", count);
 });
```

**page two**

```
 alert(localStorage.getItem("count"));
```

> Should be the same domain

Comment: i need the value of count in the php script.

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar then there are two way you can accomplish this: ajax and cookie. what method you like ?

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar ok you got your answer, gl